# Be able to continue Next Steps after a failed step (karate)

Tags: karate

In some features I need for the steps to continue (not to be skipped) after a step fails.
Is it possible to configure settings in karate?
Simplified example:

`* create product A
 Given delete a product
 When path is wrong
 Then status should be 404
 * delete product A`

So, if `Then status should be 404` fails I would like that `delete product A` be run and not be skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JS for this, refer to the doc on [conditional logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic)